# C++ output string without '\n' or endl will output '#' in the end of string

Tags: c++

On ubuntu16.04, I use g++ to compile such code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

if the string does not end with '\n' or use 'std::endl' at the last, the output will be`Hello World!#` I don't know why it ends with '#'

Comment: didnt you notice that with `\n` or `endl` the `#` is printed on the next line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't, it's your bash prompt.

You can reproduce your problem with `echo`:

```bash
# echo "Hello, World!"
Hello, World!
# echo -n "Hello, World!"
Hello, World!#
```